# python selenium sendkey doesn't work in chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, shortcut

I'm trying to launch some browser (Chrome) functions by sending shortcuts
I have tried several methods but they all cannot work.

I do this by following these steps

Initialize the browser

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir="+r"path_to_user_data")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
                      ,options=options
                     )
```

Through actionchain

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_down('T').key_up('T').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform
```

Through send_key

```
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value="/html/body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+"T")
```

But it doesn't work. This is confused for me. Why it cannot work?

Comment: The code doesn't contain `driver.get(url)`, so on which site is the driver working?

Comment: @soundwave Just the blank tab

Comment: It seems like you want to open a new tab, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to open a new tab and switch to it with a single command

```
driver.switch_to.new_window()
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my example was a bit misleading. It's not exactly what I wanted. In fact, I have a Chrome extension that I want to invoke by way of a shortcut. Ctrl+t is just an example of how I can test if the shortcut works

Comment: @silver I think you can do that with `pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 't')`, before you have to install the package `pip install pyautogui` and then `import pyautogui` in the script. Try and let me know

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing now, but I'm still looking for ways to be able to send shortcuts so that it's easier to work in the background

Comment: @silver Webdriver is designed to be used to drive the web-page, rather than to do browser specific actions. See here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=581 "This is a limitation in the way we simulate keyboard input in ChromeDriver. Keys get sent directly to the render process, bypassing the browser process. So any keyboard shortcut handlers in the browser process will not be invoked"

Comment: @silver good! you can mark the answer as accepted if it esaustively answers your question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To Open a blank new tab you can use the below:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
```

Switch to the new window

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my example was a bit misleading. It's not exactly what I wanted. In fact, I have a Chrome extension that I want to invoke by way of a shortcut. Ctrl+t is just an example to test if the shortcut works well

Comment: I think @sound wave has clarify you in more detail with example.